# How to properly store components efficiently and effectively

Tags: transistors, resistors, components, integrated-circuit, storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to store and categorise resistors/capacitors/ICs/etc?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/whats-the-best-way-to-store-and-categorise-resistors-capacitors-ics-etc)

I have MANY resistors and many other components as well and currently I am using a very cramped type of organization to store them for easy access and to be easy to find which is impossible for trying to locate certain values. If you could show me your setup it would help me very much. (If you could give me a system for storing other components as well you would make my day :) Such as how the periodic table of elements was created organization wise.

Comment: How many do you have per value? I am a shop, so for some of the frequently used values I can have 10k in stock. That asks for a very different storage than way back when I was a kid, and I used 7 x 12 glued-together matchboxes to store the resistors I salvaged from old TV sets.

Comment: Here's another similar question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10513/organizing-electronic-parts

Answer (score 2):

One method I like to use for most resistors and caps are storing them in a baseball card collection book. With some permanent marker, each "cubby hole" can provide an extremely useful catalogue.

This could be a possible choice:
[Amazon - Ultra Pro Protectors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000PWZU4E)

[image: baseball card collector sheet]

For larger components (IC's) I try not to store them in anything too special, although I have been known to use some plastic dividers meant for the purpose of storing nickknacks. ESD hasn't ruined anything yet.

Maybe something like this (others are available) [configurable storage toolboxes](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/configurable-storage-toolboxes-3-pack-4727)

Comment: Those baggies resistors come in are handy, until they flip upside down. Those card protectors are great, and most of the parts are even worth more then cards. ;)